# Want to find list index of element correpsonding to pandas dataframe (np.where with .index())

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find the index of a dictionary or a list item, where a condition meets and write it to a new column in a dataframe.

I start with the following setup:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1': ['2018_08', '2008_02','2019_01','2017_04']})

dates = {0: ['2019-01-15 00:00:00', '2019_01', 1, 2019, 0],
         -1: ['2018-12-15 00:00:00', '2018_12', 12, 2018, -1],
         -2: ['2018-11-15 00:00:00', '2018_11', 11, 2018, -2],
         -3: ['2018-10-15 00:00:00', '2018_10', 10, 2018, -3],
         -4: ['2018-09-15 00:00:00', '2018_09', 9, 2018, -4],
         -5: ['2018-08-15 00:00:00', '2018_08', 8, 2018, -5]}
```

I want to check whether the values of the column `col1` in the dataframe `df`are included in the dictionary `dates` or not. If yes, then give back the key or the last entry of the corresponding list in the dictionary. If not, then return NaT or NaN. I've tried:

```
df['month_seq'] = np.where(df.col1.isin([dates[i][1] for i in range(0,-6,-1)]), '?' ,pd.NaT)
```

which identifies the correct entries but does not return the corresponding negative numbers. The output reads as:

```
    col1    month_seq
0   2018_08     ?
1   2008_02     NaT
2   2019_01     ?
3   2017_04     NaT
```

If have tried something with

```
[dates[i][1] for i in range(0,-6,-1)].index(df.col1)
```

returning an error.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) with dictionary created by dictionary comprehension:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1': ['2018_08', '2008_02','2019_01','2017_04']})

dates = {0: ['2019-01-15 00:00:00', '2019_01', 1, 2019, 0],
         -1: ['2018-12-15 00:00:00', '2018_12', 12, 2018, -1],
         -2: ['2018-11-15 00:00:00', '2018_11', 11, 2018, -2],
         -3: ['2018-10-15 00:00:00', '2018_10', 10, 2018, -3],
         -4: ['2018-09-15 00:00:00', '2018_09', 9, 2018, -4],
         -5: ['2018-08-15 00:00:00', '2018_08', 8, 2018, -5]}

d = {v[1]:k for k, v in dates.items()}
print (d)
{'2019_01': 0, '2018_12': -1, '2018_11': -2, '2018_10': -3, '2018_09': -4, '2018_08': -5}

df['new'] = df['col1'].map(d)
print (df)
      col1  new
0  2018_08 -5.0
1  2008_02  NaN
2  2019_01  0.0
3  2017_04  NaN
```

Comment: This seems to be the fastest version. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with a proper function (`locate` in this case):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1': ['2018_08', '2008_02','2019_01','2017_04']})

dates = {0: ['2019-01-15 00:00:00', '2019_01', 1, 2019, 0],
         -1: ['2018-12-15 00:00:00', '2018_12', 12, 2018, -1],
         -2: ['2018-11-15 00:00:00', '2018_11', 11, 2018, -2],
         -3: ['2018-10-15 00:00:00', '2018_10', 10, 2018, -3],
         -4: ['2018-09-15 00:00:00', '2018_09', 9, 2018, -4],
         -5: ['2018-08-15 00:00:00', '2018_08', 8, 2018, -5]}


def locate(e, d=dates):
    for k, values in dates.items():
        if e in values:
            return k
    return np.nan


result = df['col1'].apply(locate)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
0   -5.0
1    NaN
2    0.0
3    NaN
Name: col1, dtype: float64
```